# Managing zone files

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

We host our very own **DNS server** (BIND) for various reasons, including the fact that we deploy and kill machines very often and that we sometimes need to load balance via DNS very quickly.

However, now that we have a good *60 servers*, we're kind of having a hard time keeping track of all the records and we tend to do mistakes when editing our zone file. Nothing too bad just yet (we use some other DNS provider as a backup), but I'm looking for a better way than just manually editing the file.

Also, since it's breeze for us to deploy new instances with the infamous [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef), doing this by hand is kind of what takes the most time! It would be interested if we could automate this. 
Anyone knows about this? What's a good practice to edit and maintain this zone file?

Comment: you have 60 servers but do you manage any other domain aswell or all you need to is to zone that servers within your internal/domain zone ?

Comment: Are you talking about a single internal or public domain, split domains, multiple domains or what? Simply saying 60 servers, which is nothing to those who manage thousands, doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: You're both right :(
So, it's 60 servers, all of them using subodmains of the master domain. I'm using subdomains, because they at least have the following : sub.host.tld and sub-internal.host.tld (for external and internal IPs). Some of them actually have multiple subdomains poiting to them.

Comment: What is your main target, to be able to admin everything on the command line or thru any installed webserver/browser ?

Comment: Depending on what the actual setup is, it might be much more logical and secure to use zones (split horizon dns) than host.tld and host-internal.tld

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/questions/276995/bind-http-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Chef search to dynamically build zone files as templates with Chef using the discovered hostname/fqdn and ipaddress of the nodes.

```
hosts = search(:node, "*:*")

template '/path/to/zonefile' do
  source 'zonefile.erb'
  variables(:hosts => hosts)
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0644
end
```

And the template would iterate over the `hosts` variable passed, using the hostname, fqdn and ipaddress of each result in the search. Contrived example:

```
<% @hosts.each do |h| -%>
<%= h['fqdn'] %>. IN A <%= h['ipaddress'] %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a month old now, but I just finished setting up a bit of an automated system to manage this for us. It's comprised of a git repository that contains:

1. All primary zones and config files.
2. All secondary zones and config files.
3. Build scripts for my secondary name server - Ubuntu 10.0.4LTS
4. A very simple Capistrano recipe that can update both primary and secondary name servers.

When I want to make an update to my zone files - here's the process.

```
git pull #to make sure it's current.
#Open the zone file and edit.
git diff #verify the change is what I want.
git commit -a; git push
cap primary:update #that also sends a notify to my secondary who pulls down the new zone
cap secondary:update #if I'm just updating the secondary.
```

It works really easily - I don't have to login to a bunch of servers to do anything - and it's pretty easy to see what I'm changing.

Also - it gives me a good history of changes.

If you'd like a copy of the repo - just lemme know and I'll DM you.

Comment: Yes, please give us a copy of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pain that comes with the power of text configuration. I find 60 zone files a small number to deal, unless you have to daily change them, but maybe you can get better served by a server that supports DNS data from a database (PostgreSQL, for example) like [PowerDNS](http://doc.powerdns.com/generic-mypgsql-backends.html). That allows for you to create simple scripts/pages/apps to deal with data (you can even provide a frontend to customers).

You can even configure bind to be a slave to a server using SQL it will automatically load the zone information from the master.

As for best practices:

- Keep the zone file clean of useless comments,
- Enforce correct use of tabs/spaces
- Use the domain names for the zone files
- I use `vim` macros to edit multiple files, but you can do that with sed and other tools

Comment: +1 for PDNS. Once everything is in a simple database backend, the possibilities for management are endless. Poweradmin web interface is quite nice.

Comment: Thanks Coredump and CoryJ. It's actually a lot more zones. About 150 I'd say, and we update them pretty often. Like maybe at least 3 or 4 times a week and sometimes 20 times during the same day (when we add machines to our network for example).

I'll give a shot at PowerDNS!

Comment: I had never heard of PowerDNS but it looks pretty nice.  There's even an API at https://github.com/devel/PowerDNS-API which was pointed out to me at http://irclog.perlgeek.de/crimsonfu/2012-04-24#i_5488962

Answer (score 1):

Since I assume all your servers are defined in your chef configuration, how about simply generate your zone files using that data? No idea if chef has some internal functionality for this, yet it seems like something which should be relatively trivial to script. To keep things separate it might be an idea to delegate these "dynamic" servers into a zone of their own.

That being said, are you sure you want to use DNS for loadbalancing purposes?

Comment: Well, chef is still quite unstable and DNS is kind of critical here... so I wouldn't be scared to load that directly from chef.

Is it bad to do load balancing with DNS?

Comment: Julien? Chef is unstable? Many companies are managing hundreds or even thousands of systems with it.

Answer (score 1):

Integrity validation scripts, which do things like verify the serial number has gone up, and SCM, perhaps with something like Subversion, or whatever the local preferred poison is, to have a history and ability to revert.

Once you have the data in something like svn, you can have tools which add/remove individual hosts, while still letting humans edit the zonefile.

Otherwise, there are various options for moving the data out of flat files and into databases.  PowerDNS is one, the DLZ patches for Bind are another.  I will note that in terms of performance, if these are publicly exposed zones, you probably want to keep the database-backed server as a hidden master and let AXFR/IXFR propagate changes to the public masters, which can run stock bind.  For internal zones (corp.example.com) this is likely overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Try these rules

- Configure your master DNS server to notify the slave on zone changes.
- Edit the zone files with a tool which will increment your versions automatically.  I use emacs.
- Keep your zone file in a version control system (CVS, subversion or GIT).
- Diff your zone file agains the source control system before committing it or reloading the master server. Verify your changes visually, preferably against a written change spec.  Use the change spec as a commit message.
- Use reload to update changes rather than restarting the master bind server.  Consider a script to update the zone configuration from the source control system and reload the master server in one step.
- Use short timeouts in your zone configuration.  It should be less than the exected frequency between changes.
- If your are managing both the forward and reverse zones consider using a tool that generates both files from a common specification.

Comment: "_If your are managing both the forward and reverse zones consider using a tool that generates both files from a common specification._"

Any tools you would recommend?

Comment: I haven't had control of both zones until I got ipV6.  Search google for `dns zone file generator`.  I found a Perl script and python recipe either of which should work.

Answer (score 0):

For 60 servers, the BIND module for Webmin should work well. Also check [this list](http://www.debianadmin.com/bind-dns-server-web-interfacefrontend-or-gui-tools.html)

Edit: I didn't read the first sentence of the question.

I don't know if there is a cheap way of doing this apart from rolling your own scripts, either through puppet/chef or independently.

I do know of some commercial "DNS management" solutions that sit on top of BIND. They also provide easy Web interfaces and SOAP/Rest APIs to add/remove records quickly. If needed I can provide info for these companies, as we recently evaluated several products.

Comment: How does Webmin solve the problem of automation?

Comment: It doesn't, I didn't read the first sentence of the question. :-|