# BIND HTTP "API"

Tags: mysql, domain-name-system, bind

First off, I'm a bit of a bind n00b so if I say things that don't make sense just ignore them =)

Is there any software that would allow "API" like commands for creating, updating, deleting etc. zones and records on BIND?
I have two DNS servers running on EC2 and I want to be able to easily manage domains on them from another app. I know something like CPanel has a HTTP API and interfaces with BIND but that's probably overkill for what I need. I don't mind installing Apache/PHP/Mysql/Python/Rails/Whatever else needed to get it to work but all the servers will be doing is DNS

**EDIT:**
Or get BIND to use MySQL for storing it's config, then I could just write a simple PHP script to do the 'API' bits

Comment: Any reason not to just Amazon's Route53 DNS service?

Comment: Cost =) From our data we think we'll need to host about 500 domains, but each domain might only get a few requests per day and we'll have a high TTL so I don't think we need the features of R53.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been an ongoing request from BIND admins for many years. BIND 9 has the facility built-in to swap out the storage-handling to an [alternative mechanism than the default](http://uw713doc.sco.com/en/NET_tcpip/dns.bind9sdi.html). There have been various attempts at using this facility, and one that appears to still be maintained is the [MySQL BIND SDB driver](http://mysql-bind.sourceforge.net/), which looks as if it meets the needs you edited your question to include - so you'll still need to write/find a PHP/HTTP front-end for the database.

A quick Google search for "[database backend for bind](http://www.google.co.za/search?hl=en&q=database%20backend%20for%20bind)" provides further reading, but keep in mind any such solution to include database support into BIND will require a system on which you can compile BIND + driver code, so you may want to have another host to do this on for security reasons.

As always, HTH and YMMV.

Comment: Thanks that's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I don't have a problem building my own PHP frontends so I'll spin up a couple of new EC2 instances and play about a bit

Comment: You may find the following references opens up many possibilities: http://blog.fupps.com/2010/10/29/alternative-dns-servers-the-book-as-pdf/

Answer (score 3):

You can configure a dynamic zone,

```
zone "example.com." {
    ...
    update-policy local;
};
```

and update using `nsupdate -l`:

```
$ nsupdate -l
> zone example.com
> update add foo.example.com 7200 A 1.2.3.4
> send
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an ongoing "[Name Server Control Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dickinson-dnsop-nameserver-control-02)" effort at the IETF intended to design a common API for performing exactly those functions across different DNS server implementations.

See [http://dnsccm.org/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120720084220/http://dnsccm.org/) for more details, including info about a forthcoming implementation of NSCP.

Answer (score 2):

BIND 9 comes with DLZ (http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/mysql_driver.html) included already: http://www.nlnet.nl/project/bind-dlz/

As a goodie for DLZ updates perhaps this will also be useful

http://www.ducksong.com/bind-dlz-xmlrpc-bridge.php

http://code.google.com/p/dnseditor/